# Reprocess data with strings and Numbers in Google Sheets Or Excel

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data in Google sheets Or Excel:

```
2 MG/ML
500 MCG
100 MG ; 200 MG ; 200 MCG
100 MCG/ML
325 MG ; 37.5 MG
60 G ; 9 G/1000 ML
```

I would like to have it this format. i think Regex expression could do? How i Can acheive that?:

```
all data                       Dose                Unit 
2 MG/ML                          2                 MG/ML
500 MCG                         500                MCG
100 MG ; 200 MG ; 200 MCG       100;200;200        MG;MG;MCG
100 MCG/ML                      100                MCG/ML
325 MG ; 37.5 MG                325;37.5           MG;MG
60 G ; 9 G/1000 ML              60;9               G;G/1000 ML
```

Answer (score 3):

In `B2` you could use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(;)?(?:^| +)([\d.]+)[ A-Z\/\d]+","$1$2")
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0kyNL/7)

In `C2` you could use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?:^|\s*(;))\s*[\d.]+\s*","$1")
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0kyNL/8)

Drag both down.

[image]

Comment: Wow save my life! Thanks!

Comment: @SimonGIS, you are welcome. If it has answered the question feel free to accept it as such (or the other answer offcourse).

Answer (score 2):

@JvdV has come up with a great solution. Another way to solve this is to make your own [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) with Google Apps Script, in case you need more flexibility down the line:

```
function GETDIGITS(inputString) {
  return inputString.toString().match(/(?<=^|\s)([\d.]+)(?=\s|$)/g).join(";");
}

function GETUNITS(inputString) {
  return inputString.toString().split(";").map(str => str.match(/[A-Z]+(\/[A-Z0-9\s]+)?/g)).join(";");
}
```

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mskqdSSx-H_bsscK4s-xFoiiYM3TDBq9eHCL_4TmV1M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Awesome stuff to! Thanks!